# Unable to run API in Nodejs using mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am working with nodejs(expressjs),Right now i am trying to use "API" but i am getting following error

```
{"success":false,"error":{"ok":0,"code":8000,"codeName":"AtlasError"}}
```

Here is my "Controller file"(plan-ctrl.js)

```
export const getPlans = async (req, res) => {
    await Plan.find({}, (err, plans) => {
        if (err) {
            return res.status(400).json({ success: false, error: err })
        }
        if (!plans.length) {
            return res
                .status(404)
                .json({ success: false, error: `Plans not found` })
        }
        return res.status(200).json({ success: true, data: plans })
    }).clone().catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

Here is my "model" (plan-model.js)

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const Plan = new Schema(
    {
        name:  { type: String, required: true },
        price:  { type: Number, required: true },
        branches:  { type: Number, required: true },
        flows:  { type: Number, required: true },
        assignees:  { type: Number, required: true },
        gitignore:  { type: Boolean, required: true },
        priority:  { type: Boolean, required: true },
        multistore:  { type: Boolean, required: true },
    }
)
export default mongoose.model('plans', Plan)
Here is my data in database(mongodb/mongoose) in "claudmongo" ( connection established successfully)
_id : ObjectId(6390bfacbe1XXXXXXXXXXXX)
name:"Free"
price:"0"
branches:"2"
flows:2
assignees:null
gitignore:null
priority:null
multistore:false
color:"#969696"
...
```

Comment: Most likely an authentication issue. Check your credentials

Comment: @tiborK as i said "connection established successfully"

Comment: but you have shown success: false message

Comment: @SrushtiShah you are right but i was getting "error message" but now i am getting message "Server running on port 3001 ", so thats why i saying there is no issue with "credentials"

Comment: so what result you are expecting ? and where is the API ? can you add your API ?

Comment: @SrushtiShah already shared my code , (trying to get data from mongdb atlas) 
code is like
"const uri ="mongodb+srv://technxxxxx:lrFdlxxxxx@orbxxxxxxxxx.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority"